# split an array string (split is not working) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I have an array like **["one, two, three"]**.
I want to convert it to **["one","two","three"]**.
I was using **split** to do this like:

```
$var temp=["one, two, three"];
temp.split(", ");
```

This is giving me error. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NXDWp/2/

Comment: ["one, two, three"] - with this it is not working ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an array with one single value, and you'd access that with `[0]` to get the string

```
var temp = ["one, two, three"];
var arr  = temp[0].split(", ");
```

seems easier to just drop the brackets

```
var arr = "one, two, three".split(', ');
```

or write it as an array to begin with ?

Answer (score 0):

```
["one, two, three"].pop().split(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp=["one, two, three"];
temp[0].split(", ")
```